# Why is Hibernate trying to access hibernate_sequence when using strategy GenerationType.IDENTITY?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

In my project, I am using MySQL with Hibernate and JPA. My entities are all annotated with `@ID @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Nevertheless, Hibernate tries to select the next ID from the table `hibernate_sequence` when inserting new objects into the database - which fails obviously.

I checked for the whole project whether a different generation type was used by accident on some entity, but this is not the case. What else could cause this problem?

This is the SQL i use to create my tables:

```
create table versioned_string_attribute (
  id int primary key auto_increment not null,
  timestamp timestamp,
  value text
);


create table backend_address (
  id int primary key auto_increment not null,
  street_id int references versioned_string_attribute(id),
  house_number_id int references versioned_string_attribute(id),
  zip_code_id int references versioned_string_attribute(id),
  town_id int references versioned_string_attribute(id),
  addition_id int references versioned_string_attribute(id)
);
```

And here is my `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) the property:

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= # Whether to use Hibernate's newer IdentifierGenerator for AUTO, TABLE and SEQUENCE.

So I solved this issue by adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false`

More details about this: https://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/